# Same delegates with different params in TPL Dataflow blocks

Tags: vb.net, delegates, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, addressof

My TPL Dataflow pipeline uses multiple same blocks, the only difference is each of them uses it's personal proxy to send http requests. So `WebProxy` here is a parameter. I act like this to create them (conceptual simpled example, `WebProxy` replaced with `blockNum Integer`):

```
Private Sub CreateBlocks()
    Dim blocks As New List(Of TransformBlock(Of Integer, Integer))
    For i = 0 To 100
        Dim blockNum As Integer = i
        Dim block As New TransformBlock(Of Integer, Integer)(Function(_arg)
                                                                 Return _arg + blockNum
                                                             End Function)
        blocks.Add(block)
    Next
End Sub
```

I use a lambda expressions. It causes some troubles. So the question is: How can I replace it with Delegate function. I mean use `AddressOf` Smthn. I need to pass `blockNum` to each block somehow.

**UPDATE:**

There are two kind of troubles why I don't wanna use a lambda:

First: my lambda-expression is too big, it's very hard to work with it and modify it in editor: whole expression became error if something wrong.

Second: I want to create a base class with Dataflow pipeline, and change only blocks delegates in derived classes.

Comment: What kind of troubles does it cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not move all of the code from the lambda to a real function. Then create a small lambda that captures blockNum and passes it to said function?